# Show that exists $0\neq v_0\in V$ such that $V = \ker f \oplus[v_0]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ vector space and $0\neq f\in V^*$(dual). Show that exists $0\neq v_0\in V$ such that $V = \ker f \oplus[v_0]$.

Comment: Take any $v_0$ such that $f(v_0)\not=0$ and try to find $\alpha$ such that $f(x-\alpha v_0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take any $v_0\in V\setminus{\rm Ker}f$, then $v_0\neq 0$ and for all $v\in V$,
$$ v=\underbrace{\frac{f(v)}{f(v_0)}v_0}_{\in\mathbb{K}v_0}+\underbrace{\left(v-\frac{f(v)}{f(v_0)}v_0\right)}_{\in{\rm Ker}f} $$
so that $V={\rm Ker}f+\mathbb{K}v_0$. Moreover, if $v\in{\rm Ker}f\cap\mathbb{K}v_0$, there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$ such that $v=\lambda v_0$, therefore $0=f(v)=\lambda f(v_0)$ thus $\lambda=0$ because $v_0\notin{\rm Ker}f$ and $v=0$ so ${\rm Ker}f\cap\mathbb{K}v_0=\{0\}$ and therefore $V={\rm Ker}f\oplus\mathbb{K}v_0$.